# Querying (SQL) Oracle/Toad dump files without importing them

Tags: sql, oracle, dump, toad

We're doing a monthly data dump of our databases using Toad for Oracle's Export function. We've got some SQL queries to create statistics about the data. I'd like to compare the results of the current state with the last few dumps.

I can open the files with the Export File Browser in Toad (v11) and sort/filter the data using the GUI, but that's not powerful enough. Is there a way to query the dump files with SQL without having to take extra steps like creating a new schema and importing it?

Comment: if the dump files are formatted then search for `external tables` in oracle. you basically create an oracle object called `directory` that points to where the dump files are on the OS. then you create an `external table` object and write the import script using `SQL*Loader` syntax (best when the dump files are formatted like csv). then, every time you query the table oracle loads the file, and import the data to the database.

Comment: Well I would definitely be gathering these statistics and storing them in the database prior to exporting them. I'd also be wondering why you're doing monthly data exports of course.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way would be to reimport the data.